# linking social media pages to buttons in my app

Tags: facebook, swift

I am trying to link my Facebook page to a button in my app, I want it to open the Facebook page so the person can like my page. I also want to do the same for twitter. 
Below is my current code, I have added a IBAction to the button with the following code. The error i keep getting is expected expression in container literal

```
   import UIKit



class SocialViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




     @IBAction func openFacebook(sender: UIButton) {

       //Open Facebook App
       if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/idnumber"]]) {

         //opeing the app didnt work now Open safari
         if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL,: [NSURL             URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"]]) {


  }


      }




      }


   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Objective-C style code.

This is swift:

```
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/idnumber")!) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "fb://profile/idnumber")!)
} else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://facebook.com/")!)
}
```

Comment: will that open the app first if it is installed on the device?

Comment: thanks, that worked. is it the same procedure for twitter? just fb would change to tw?